# Flash: Why Flash doesn't recognize a Primesense/Flash camera?

Tags: flash, camera, kinect, primesense

I'd like to know if there is some documentation available to know how Flash detects webcams in order to know why it cannot get a Primesense/Kinect camera.

I think it'd be really useful to access Kinect without using the OpenKinect scheme (server-client), but using a real driver for Flash based on Video4Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't answer your question in full I can provide some insight as to why it is currently not working or well documented.

1. Kinect is not a simple webcam. As we all know it is not a standard USB device and does not produce the standard stream expected from a webcam. This is why Adobe's webcam implamentation doesn't work.
2. You can use the client/server method you spoke of. You can either use openNI or the actual Kinect SDK to create a proxy to get the data. These could even run off the same machine. I would suggest using the actual Kinect SDK's Kinect Server to collect the data and simply make a web-service that hands up the raw skeletal data, depth data, or RGB camera data however you need it. Although it would require some knowledge of C# to get it working it wouldn't be that hard to do.
3. You could also use as3Kinect... although unstable currently it does exactly what you are looking for (access to the RGB data without an external program) http://www.as3kinect.org/

Edit: wanted to add: http://zigfu.com/

hope this helps
David Bates

Comment: All of the above points are correct. The best way to interact with Flash/Air with Kinect would some kind of TCP socket - which is how libraries such as Omek provide a flash interface to TOF sensors.

Comment: TCP way is not suitable to manage 1280x1024 images (max. resolution of Asus WAVI Xtion or Primensense)...I could test it.

Comment: It'd be interesting to build a video4linux driver which is feeded by the video stream from Asus/Primesense driver...is it crazy?

Comment: It would be clunky to send an 1280x1024 image across the wire for every frame. I was mainly speaking to skeletal data. However the proxy you would build contains that data and could manipulate it. For instance you could reduce the image or provide it to flash in a container it could stream like mjpeg, mp4, etc.